# Discord bot goes offline and stops responding

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, python-asyncio, pycord

I'm using [Pycord library](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/index.html) to develop my discord bot. I'm using `asyncpg`, so I do not use regular `bot.run()` because it takes control over a loop and I cannot properly execute db queries, they all give **Task is already in progress** kind of error.

Maybe there's something wrong with my implementation of bot launch, but the first 5-10 minutes bot works fine, responding to commands and executing everything alright. Later then, bot goes offline and I only get `on_ready()` event firing every 10 minutes, `on_connect()` does not fire (screenshot of log attached)

After the **Bot is ready!** message bot goes online for 2-3 minutes and then back offline.

[image]

Here's the whole **main.py** script, just scroll down to the `main()` function. Left event cog here in case maybe I messed up some of the events and the issue lies there.

```
import asyncio
import os
import sys

import discord
from database import Database
from embeds import DefaultEmbed, LinkEmbed
from environ_loader import load_env
from logger import Log
from owner_commands import OwnerCog
from twitch import TwitchRequests
from ui import LinkView


class EventCog(discord.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot: discord.Bot = bot
        self.db: Database = None

    @discord.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        self.db: Database = self.bot.db
        Log.success("Bot is ready!")

    @discord.Cog.listener()
    async def on_connect(self):
        await self.bot.sync_commands()
        Log.info("Connected to the servers")

    @discord.Cog.listener()
    async def on_guild_join(self, guild: discord.Guild):
        channel = guild.system_channel
        if channel:
            channel = channel.id
        await self.db.add_guild(guild.id, channel)

    @discord.Cog.listener()
    async def on_guild_remove(self, guild: discord.Guild):
        print(f"Should delete {guild.id}")
        print(await self.db.remove_guild(guild.id))

    async def setup_hook(self):
        bot.db = await Database.connect()


perms = discord.Permissions()
intents = discord.Intents()
perms.manage_roles = True
intents.guilds = True
bot = discord.Bot(permissions=perms, intents=intents, debug_guilds=[696434683730329713])


@bot.slash_command(description="For sure!")
async def link(
    ctx: discord.ApplicationContext,
    twitch_url: discord.Option(str, "Enter the twitch streamer link")
):
    try:
        data = await TwitchRequests.getChannelInfo(twitch_url)
    except Exception as e:
        Log.failure(str(e))
    else:
        await ctx.respond(embed=LinkEmbed(
            twitch_name=data["login"],
            twitch_description=data["description"],
            twitch_thumbnail=data["profile_image_url"],
            creation_date=data["created_at"],
            is_partner=data["broadcaster_type"] == "partner"
        ), view=LinkView())


async def main():
    events = EventCog(bot)
    ownerCommands = OwnerCog(bot)
    bot.add_cog(events)
    bot.add_cog(ownerCommands)

    await bot.login(os.getenv("BOT_TOKEN"))
    await bot.application_info()
    DefaultEmbed.bot_name = bot.user.name
    DefaultEmbed.bot_thumnail_url = bot.user.avatar.url
    await events.setup_hook()
    await bot.connect()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    load_env()
    TwitchRequests.init()
    if os.name == "nt":
        asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())

    Log.info("Launching discord bot")
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
        print("COMPLETED")
    finally:
        if sys.exc_info()[0] is None:
            Log.info("Bot offline")
```

#### UPDATE

Even that I said i cannot use regular `bot.run()`, I tested it and it went fine, it didn't disconnect, I guess the answer lies in `bot.run()` implementation. I did something wrong in my `main()` coroutine. The next this is to figure out what exactly i did wrong.

Comment: Where are you hosting your bot?

Comment: Local computer, current OS is Windows 10. It's still in development

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg, I included everything that needed to be included, and nothing more. You can re-read my question and see why I did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem solved!

`Bot` is inherited from `Client`, which accepts `loop` in init method. If it is not passed, it will create a **new event loop**, which will interfere with my snippet of code somehow and create those annoying periodical connects/disconnects.

So, the solution is to create a loop **before** bot initialization and pass current loop in `discord.Bot()` constructor like so:

```
 discord.Bot(permissions=perms, intents=intents, debug_guilds=[...], loop=loop)
```

###### P.S:

It also solved a problem with **autocomplete** in slash commands. Before I couldn't do anything because it was constantly saying that the bot loop and loop where the command was executed are different. Now it's working perfectly fine and even better! =)